# How can i solve fatal error regard memory space

Tags: magento-1.9, error

Just am hosting, when i try to reindex, i got this error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase limit in php.ini file following below steps, php.ini

Find the following section in the php.ini file.

max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 128M

Try increase the memory_limit value to 256M.

If the php memory_limit is already at 256M, you can increase it to 512M.
Save the changes.

Comment: how can change in godaddy cpanel

Comment: where i can change php.ini in cpanel

Comment: Login to your cPanel.
Go to the File Manager.
Select the Web root (public_html/www) directory and click Go.
Find the php.ini file in the public_html.
Open the php.ini with the code editor.

Comment: i get Same error